# Converter data para dd/MM/yyyy ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Como formatar **sysdate** para **dd/MM/yyyy** no Oracle 11g?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS data_formatada FROM tabela
```

Answer (score 3):

Podemos utilizar o formato de ano RRRR, que faz o reconhecimento do século para converter o ano sendo necessário somente 2 dígitos, por exemplo 50 como ainda não chegamos em 2050 será convertido para o ano 1950, mas se for preenchido com 10 será retornado 2010, conforme o exemplo.

```
 SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/50','DD/MM/RRRR'), 
        TO_DATE('01/01/10','DD/MM/RRRR'), 
        TO_DATE('01/01/50','DD/MM/YYYY') 
   FROM DUAL
```